# Yet another JNI related java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have been through so many forum posts on similar issues, but I feel like I've seen it all. In short I have Native code through the wonders of JNI, accessed by Java. The code worked fine before I started using JAVA packages. I have followed all forum posts about ensuring the Javah cmd runs in the correct folder, and have successfully built my DLL. I have ensured that the package in which the wrapper is contained is present in the names of the C++ functions. Due to the size of the project I will simply show an example of this code. NOTE all the code (DLL's, JVM C++ Compiler) operates in 32-bit, and the target is a PC running windows 8.1.

All my Java Code is contained in the package:

```
package com.optin.executableContainer.client;
```

So in my Java wrapper class, I load the DLL(32-bit) expressly as follows

```
static
{
System.load("C:\\JNITests\\JNIBridge.dll"); 
}
```

I know this loads the DLL as without the DLL in that folder I get the "Cannot load library" Run-time error. The header code used, generated by the javah -jni command is

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_optin_executableContainer_client_COMControl_setControlBackColor
(JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong);
```

The asscociated C++ code contained within a .cpp file is:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_optin_executableContainer_client_COMControl_setControlBackColor
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong color)
{
printf("\nHello World\n");
}
```

There are no errors when I compile this with Visual Studio 2010. I have verified that this function exists within the targeted DLL, by using DLL export viewer which sees the function name as:

```
void __stdcall Java_com_optin_executableContainer_client_COMControl_setControlBackColor(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *,__int64)
```

However when I run this code, in the Eclipse IDE, I get the dreaded

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    com.optin.executableContainer.client.COMControl.setControlBackColor(J)V
at com.optin.executableContainer.client.COMControl.setControlBackColor(Native Method)
```

If I have missed something along the way, please point it out to me.

Regards
Jarren

**UPDATED:** 
I went and compared the working dll (done before the packaging) and the new dll and spotted a few major differences. Here is the function name of the unpackaged working dll

```
_Java_COMControl_destroy@8
```

And here is the function name of the new packaged, unworking dll

```
void __stdcall Java_com_optin_executableContainer_client_COMControl_destroy(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jobject *)
```

The Java code `COMControl.java` (that produces the COMControl header) declares this function as follows

```
private native void destroy();
```

I have tried comparing the differences between the header file that produced the working one and that producing the broken one, and other than the obvious packaging based changes (com_optin etc) there are no other differences. The only difference in the `COMControl.java` file is the inclusion of the `package com.optin.executableContainer.client;` at the top of the Java file.

What is going on here?

Comment: The function needs to be exported from the dll as a *plain* c function, not as a name-mangled `c++` function. If you see a list of parameters in the DLL export viewer then it sounds like you've exported the function as a name mangled function. declare the function as `extern "C"` and recompile

Comment: I have done that in the C++ header. The JNIBridge.h file generated by the Javah cmd contains the wrappers                           
extern "C" {} for the entire header file. There is a #ifdef __cplusplus for the extern command, but that shouldnt be a problem, right?

Comment: you do `#include` the header that contains the `extern "C"` declaration in the `.cpp` file - if you don't, then the linkage type isn't applied

Comment: I have included the #include "JNIBridge.h" in the "JNIBridge.cpp" which contains the code, and have tried it with the #include in the stadfx.h file and without it.

Comment: If I may ask, what does a `plain C` function look like versus a name-mangled `C++` function. I am curious whether the `extern "C"` code is affecting the dll or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting the native routine as a name-mangled `C++` function. The reason we can tell this is because the parameters to the function are listed in the export information of the library. Whenever you can tell the types of the parameters that are being passed in the name of a function it implies that the function is being exported as a decorated `C++` method. If you looked at the raw export information of the library without demangling, it would look something like:

```
?Java_Package_ComControl_destroy@@YGXPAUJNIEnv_@@PAV_jobject@@@Z
```

When it looks like this, the java run-time cannot find it, it is supposed to look more like:

```
_Java_Package_ComControl_destroy@8
```

which is an undecorated `C` routine. The `@8` is stdcall shorthand for 8 bytes are passed in the stack to the routine

The most common reason for this happening is that the `.h` file which declares the function and was generated by javah **does not match** the `.cpp` file that defines the content of the function - i.e. there is some subtle difference between the `.h` file and the `.cpp` file. You should copy-paste the declaration of the function in the `.h` file into the `.cpp` file, making sure that all the parameters line up and that all the types line up.

Additionally, for the `.cpp` file, you have to make sure that it `#include`s the `.h` file that was generated by javah, and doesn't just does `#include <jni.h>`. If you don't do this then the compiler will not know that the routine is to be exported as a `C` style routine. This is a common reason why the resulting compiled dll does not contain the unmangled version of the method.

If you want to manually enforce the routines being exported using the undecorated `C` calling convention, in the `.cpp` file, at the function definition, you can put in:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_optin_executableContainer_client_COMControl_setControlBackColor
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong color)
{
    printf("\nHello World\n");
}
```

By using the `extern "C"` in that manner, the function will be defined for export as a `C` routine rather than a `C++` routine; but this is undesirable as you should really be including the `.h` that came from `javah`.

I don't know if visual studio has an equivalent to the `-Wmissing-declarations` of `gcc` which notices inconsistencies like this, which are kind of important for `.dll`s.

Comment: I did a blank copy of the cpp file using the .h file, and It still didnt work. Only putting the `extern "C"` before every function in the cpp file finally solved the dll naming issues, and allowing my java program to run the native code within the DLL. What I am confused about is that in the header file generated by the javah excecutable, there is a `extern "C" {...}`. It is contained within a `#ifdef __cplusplus` but should this make a difference? Does Visual Studio not provide define this during the compilation/pre-compiler stage.

Comment: As long as you're `#including` the `.h` file *in the `.cpp` file that contains the declarations* it really should be doing the right thing (I don't know, though, if it works properly with `stdafx.h` which is why I always directly `#include` the generated `.h` in the `.cpp` file). the `__cplusplus` define should *always* exist when compiling `C++` code, otherwise many, many things would be horrendously broken.